# keepalivedでクライアントサーバとの通信が失敗する

Tags: linux, centos, network

keepalivedで、特定のvirtual ip宛でアクセスが来たら、クライアントサーバへ向かわせる処理を行なっています。

ですがホストからクライアントへ「telnet ipアドレス 80」は通信が成功するのに、keepalivedではログに「Keepalived_healthcheckers[5189]: Timeout WEB read server」が表示されてしまいます。weightも0になります。

設定など見直しているのですが、いまいち原因がわかりません。

この問題を解決するためのヒントをいただければ幸いです。

環境
centos6.7

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101531

Comment: 「クライアントサーバ」は一般的に言う「サーバ」のことでしょうか(keepalivedの用語?） 「ホスト」「クライアント」と出てきますが、文脈から言うと「ホスト」が「サーバ」を指しているということになりますが、それでいいですか。

Comment: ホスト：keepalivedが入っているサーバ、クライアント：先に述べたホストを経由させて最終的にアクセスさせたいところ　になります。分かりにくくてすみません。